# Android play music in a random amount of time

Tags: android

Now I can play a music in android. But I want to play this sound in a random amount of time between 2 to 8 seconds.How Can I randomly play it that for example the first time, it plays for 2 seconds, the next time 7 sec and so on? Can anybody help me?

Comment: you could generate a random number each time a user clicks on play. then you play the song and set a timer with that random number. when the timer reaches the amount of that number you stop the song.

Comment: can I have a sample code of it?

Answer (score 3):

Go through these links:

[Random number Generation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html)

[Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

[Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

you will get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Sound in android is played like this :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int mSoundID = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
            float lActualVolume = (float) audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float lMaxVolume = (float) audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float lVolume = lActualVolume / lMaxVolume;
            // Is the sound loaded already?
            if (mSoundIsLoaded) {
                mSoundPool.play(mSoundID, lVolume, lVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

I think you have been given plenty of help to figure the random number part out.
You will have to put the sound file in your assets/raw directory.

edit:
I forgot to mention where the mSoundIsLoaded parameter came from.
I set it when my sound has been loaded. I do this in my onCreate method. when the sound is loaded I set the boolean field called mSoundIsLoaded. I do this to prevent NullPointerExceptions when playing the sound
the loading of the sound looks like this:

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
            mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    mSoundIsLoaded = true;
                }
            });
            mSoundID = mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
```